# How do I change the Lion menubar selection color?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, menu-bar

I really hate the blue-purple color of the Lion (and Snow Leopard before it) menu bar selection. Isn't there some way to change this? I've tried tweaking everything, but Apple seems to have decided that we should all use this absurdly bright color unless we want to go totally monochrome and use Graphite (which I don't). I assume the same fix should apply to Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System preferences > General > Appearance > [Blue|Graphite]

[image]

Graphite will turn menu selection co
lor to dark grey. Of course it's system wide so it also will change the color for other UI elements.

---

Modding

You will need :

- [SArtFileTool](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=819838)
- image editor
- a good backup ;-)

Download SArtFileTool into ~/Downloads/SArtFile then copy and decompress the system art resource file :

```
cd ~/Downloads/SArtFile
cp /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/SArtFile.bin ./
./sartfiletool -d SArtFile.bin artfiles
```

Go into the artfiles directory and find 52.png 68.png 71.png files and modify them.

- 52.png = "Blue" top menu text selection color
- 68.png = "Blue" menu item text selection color
- 71.png = "Blue" help menu item "Search" background color

Then recreate SArtFile.bin and put into place :

```
./sartfiletool -e artfiles SArtFile.bin SArtFile.new.bin
sudo cp SArtFile.new.bin /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/SArtFile.bin
```

Logout & log in again, menu should look something like this (I cheated and used the turquoise-ish files from ["Lion Pulse" mod](http://neodesktop.deviantart.com/art/LionPulse-Alpha-1-244337754?offset=10).)

[image: modified menu]

Additional remarks:
The SArtFile is poorly documented for Lion, here's the explanation of the contents for [Snow Leopard](http://macthemes.net/wiki/10.6_SArtFile.bin) but Lion's is different.
The selection in Finder is still the harsher blue, haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should've mentioned that I don't want to switch to Graphite. I'm ashamed to admit it, but I kinda like the candy-colored window controls.

Comment: I knew I had seen this mod and it was possible, so I looked it up for you (see edits above.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I liked LionPulse so much I just used that. I can't believe this is so complicated, but it's good to know it can be done.

Comment: The [file names of the graphic files changed on Mountain Lion](http://superuser.com/a/471401/69039). The binary linked on the first page of the thread doesn't currently work on 10.8, but you can [compile a newer version yourself](https://github.com/alexzielenski/sartFileTool).