# Is it possible to change the gray color scheme of Lion?

Tags: macos, safari

Seems to be too much gray in Lion.  Status bar, title bar, scroll bars, links bar, tabs, everything blends into itself.

I am guessing that is part of the design. Any options to changes these?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a subtle change away from gray shifting towards blue with theOS preferences. Go to Apple Menu -> System Preferences...

Then click on General in the upper left

[image]

And then select Blue under appearance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an awful lot you can do, but as a start, you could get the colored [iTunes icons](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/26/bring-back-color-itunes-icons-os-x-lion/) or [Finder sidebar icons](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/get-color-sidebar-icons-back-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-finder-windows/) back like they used to be in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to mod the color scheme but it involves changing resource files and is not for the faint of heart. Refer to my answer to the question ["How do I change the Lion menubar selection color?"](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/how-do-i-change-the-lion-menubar-selection-color/25810#25810). There are some ready made mods ([BlackPurple](http://neodesktop.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d4w41l6), [LionPulse](http://neodesktop.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d4p16ce)) on Deviant Art.